# VS2013: Team Explorer, new team project, solutions view showing unversioned solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

I added a new team project, and placed the solution under source control. The source control correctly picks out all the projects, and The 'Source Control Explorer' view is correct.

However the Team Explorer View, (the 'Home' of the project), under solutions has picked up 3 solutions which where all in the same folder or sub-folder that was originally selected for the 'new team project'. 
1 of the solutions is the correct solution, the same one I put under source control. 2 other solutions are showing up in that view and I don't want them to be displayed, They are in a 'backup' folder, and would like to keep them in that folder, but I do not want them showing up in the Team Explorer view.

[image]

Comment: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/06/11/tfs1.png

Comment: I have a work-around. Zip the 'Backup' folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by mapping a different workspace that excludes those folders. The team explorer is showing you every solution in your current workspace.